# Interpreting AUC, accuracy and f1-score on the unbalanced dataset

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tensorflow2.0, multiclass-classification, auc

I am trying to understand how AUC is a better metric than classification accuracy in the case when the dataset is unbalanced.
Suppose a dataset is containing 1000 examples of 3 classes as follows:

```
a = [[1.0, 0, 0]]*950 + [[0, 1.0, 0]]*30 + [[0, 0, 1.0]]*20
```

Clearly, this data is unbalanced.
A naive strategy is to predict every point belonging to the first class.
Suppose we have a classifier with the following predictions:

```
b = [[0.7, 0.1, 0.2]]*1000
```

With the true labels in the list `a` and predictions in the list `b`, classification accuracy is 0.95.
So one would believe that the model is really doing good on the classification task, but it is not because the model is predicting every point in one class.
Therefore, the AUC metric is suggested for evaluating an unbalanced dataset.
If we predict AUC using TF Keras [AUC](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/AUC) metric, we obtain ~0.96.
If we predict f1-score using sklearn [f1-score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html) metric by setting `b=[[1,0,0]]*1000`, we obtain 0.95.

Now I am a little bit confused because all the metrics (Accuracy, AUC and f1-score) are showing high value which means that the model is really good at the prediction task (which is not the case here).

Which point I am missing here and how we should interpret these values?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are very likely using the `average='micro'` parameter to calculate the F1-score. According to the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html#sklearn.metrics.f1_score), specifying `'micro'` as the averaging strategy will:

> Calculate metrics globally by counting the total true positives, false negatives and false positives.

In classification tasks where every test case is guaranteed to be assigned to exactly one class, computing a micro F1-score is equivalent to computing the accuracy score. Just check it out:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score

y_true = [[1, 0, 0]]*950 + [[0, 1, 0]]*30 + [[0, 0, 1]]*20
y_pred = [[1, 0, 0]]*1000

print(accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)) # 0.95

print(f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='micro')) # 0.9500000000000001
```

You basically computed the same metric twice. By specifying `average='macro'` instead,  the F1-score will be computed for each label independently first, and then averaged:

```
print(f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')) # 0.3247863247863248
```

As you can see, the overall F1-score depends on the averaging strategy, and a macro F1-score of less than 0.33 is a clear indicator of a model's deficiency in the prediction task.

---

## EDIT:

Since the OP asked when to choose which strategy, and I think it might be useful for others as well, I will try to elaborate a bit on this issue.

`scikit-learn` actually implements four different stratagies for metrics that support averages for multiclass and multilabel classification tasks. Conveniently, the `classification_report` will return all of those that apply for a given classification task for *Precision*, *Recall* and *F1-score*:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

# The same example but without nested lists. This avoids sklearn to interpret this as a multilabel problem.
y_true = [0 for i in range(950)] + [1 for i in range(30)] + [2 for i in range(20)]
y_pred = [0 for i in range(1000)]

print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred, zero_division=0))

######################### output ####################

              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.95      1.00      0.97       950
           1       0.00      0.00      0.00        30
           2       0.00      0.00      0.00        20

    accuracy                           0.95      1000
   macro avg       0.32      0.33      0.32      1000
weighted avg       0.90      0.95      0.93      1000
```

All of them provide a different perspective depending on how much emphasize one puts on the class distributions.

1. `micro` average is a global strategy that basically ignores that there is a distinction between classes. This might be useful or justified if someone is really just interested in overall disagreement in terms of true positives, false negatives and false positives, and is not concerned about differences within the classes. As hinted before, if the underlying problem is not a multilabel classification task, this actually equals the accuracy score. (This is also why the `classification_report` function returned `accuracy` instead of `micro avg`).
2. `macro` average as a strategy will calculate each metric for each label separately and return their unweighted mean. This is suitable if each class is of equal importance and the result shall not be skewed in favour of any of the classes in the dataset.
3. `weighted` average will also first calculate each metric for each label separately. But the average is weighted according to the classes' support. This is desirable if the importance of the classes is proportional to their importance, i.e. a class that is underrepresented is considered less important.
4. `samples` average is only meaningful for multilabel classification and therefore not returned by `classification_report` in this example and also not discussed here ;)

So the choice of averaging strategy and the resulting number to trust really depends on the importance of the classes. Do I even care about class differences (if no --> micro average) and if so, are all classes equally important (if yes --> macro average) or is the class with higher support more important (--> weighted average).

Comment: So how we decide about the averaging technique in computing AUC and f1-score because these results are suggesting very different interpretations of the models performance?

Comment: Also prediction is correct for a large number of samples, so f1 score using macro averaging is not taking that into account.

Comment: You are right about the macro average. It is meant to weight all separate metrics equally and neglect the support of the classes in the dataset. This is why the large number of correctly classified samples of the majority class is marginalized. If you want to consider this aspect as well, you could e.g. use the weighted average which will account for the support of the classes as well.

Comment: Also see that I updated my answer to give you and others an idea when which strategy is suitable. I hope this clarifies things.

Comment: @afsharov Brilliant and clarifying answer - many thanks!